# Grammaticality and register of: 'In my pencil case there are scissors/a pair of scissors' versus 'There is a scissors'

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage

I am trying to understand how to use the word *scissors*, I have read this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/is-pair-of-scissors-more-correct-than-scissors)
and I would like to ask if this information is correct. Am I right about these sentences?

> 1. In my pencil case there are scissors (Grammatically correct, informal)
> 2. In my pencil case there are a pair of scissors (Grammatically correct, more formal than (1))
> 3. In my pencil case there is a scissors (Grammatically incorrect, common in spoken language and informal speech. For some natives it simply sounds wrong)

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: I would like to ask if this information is correct

Comment: We have a sister site SE English Language Learners which, in my opinion, is more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: See also: [When is it correct to use "scissors" as a singular noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400138) Different speakers disagree about which usages sound correct (not only ELL learners, but also native speakers).

Comment: Related: ["The pair was ..." or "the pair were ..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31783); [Why is the poker hand called "two pair" and not "two pairs"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/389000); [Should the process of two galaxies merging be treated as grammatically singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/423932); [There is / There are](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/171703).

Comment: (1a) 'In my pencil case there are scissors' (Grammatically correct but formal); (1b) 'There are scissors in my pencil case' (Grammatically correct and not marked for register); (1b) 'There's [a pair of] scissors in my pencil case' (Idiomatic / conversational).

Comment: I have scissors in my pencil case. How about you?

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct but not as informative as it might be. One pair, or more than one?
2. Incorrect. “Pair” is singular. It has to be “there is a pair of scissors”. Then it is both correct and more informative than 1.
3. Incorrect, as you say yourself, because “scissors” is in form a plural. I am surprised that you say it is common in spoken language and informal speech. That is not my experience. I would think that for all native speakers, and not just some, it would definitely sound wrong.

Comment: People often use *there's* as an abbreviation for *there are*. So *there's scissors in my pencil case* isn't uncommon, and it's possible the OP could have heard this and expanded the contraction.

Comment: Hello, EMC. Please add supporting evidence for claims. In particular, the question of whether 'scissors' should nowadays be considered correctly used as a plural-form singular count noun taking singular verb agreement (?'a scissors lay on the medical tray') is moot, and well discussed in the duplicate thread [[When is it correct to use 'scissors' as a singular noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400138/when-is-it-correct-to-use-scissors-as-a-singular-noun)]